# How to add and remove exact element in Vue.JS?

Tags: vue.js

Good Day, I am new in Vue, so don't judge)
I created a feature that can add and remove inputs.

*Vue Template Part*

```
<div>

<div v-for="(input, indexOfInputs) in inputs" v-bind:key="input.id">
    <input type="text">
    <p @click="deleteRow(indexOfInputs)">Remove Input</p>
</div>

<p @click="addRow">Add Input</p>

</div>
```

*Sctipt part*

```
data: () => {
    inputs: [],
},

methods: {
    addRow() {
        this.inputs.push({
            one: '',
        });
    },
    deleteRow(indexOfInputs) {
        this.inputs.splice(indexOfInputs, 1);
    },
}
```

It works perfectly, but what if I would have for about 100 forms? 
 I mean 100 of `div`s like this:

```
<div>

<div v-for="(input, indexOfInputs) in inputs" v-bind:key="input.id">
    <input type="text">
    <p @click="deleteRow(indexOfInputs)">Remove Input</p>
</div>

<p @click="addRow">Add Input</p>

</div>
```

If I will create, for example, 100 blocks and then click at ANY of *"Add Input"*, **it will add 100 inputs instead of 1.**

I won't create 100 methods, but what I should do then?
I have hear something about `event.taget`, but I have no idea how to use it in this case..

Comment: what do you mean 100 forms?  please give an example of what your desired would be look like

Comment: What you did is just fine, you can know which form input to delete based on the index (or even better pass the ID to the function), then all you need to do is make sure your render reflects your updated data. No need for more than one function.

Comment: I've updated the summery, so you will probably understand what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function), data value in vue components should be a function. If it's not, then all the properties inside data would be shared among all the instances of the same component.

You can write it like this:

```
data: function () {
  return {
    inputs: []
  }
}
```

Shorter syntax with ES6 arrow functions:

```
data: () => ({
    inputs: [],
})
```